# ExchangeServiceBinding namespace error

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, exchangewebservices

Summary: application will not accept the `ExchangeServiceBinding` command.

---

Details:

I am trying to loop through a very large mailbox, so I am using an index to break the inbox into 200 email chunks. The only example I could find (shown below) keeps returning

> the type or namespace name “ExchangeServiceBinding” could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )

Which I find strange, because I am using it `using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices;`. Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated. I am running Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 and trying to access Exchange 2007 mailboxes.

---

Things I've tried:

- searching Google
- searching Stack Overflow
- searching MSDN
- slamming my head on my desk
- trial and error

---

Code:

```
// Create binding variable to be used for GetItemsFromInbox().
// Set up the binding with credentials and URL.
ExchangeServiceBinding binding = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
binding.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dUser, dPassword, dDomain);
binding.Url = new Uri("https://" + ExchangeServerName + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

// Set up the binding for Exchange impersonation.
binding.ExchangeImpersonation = new ExchangeImpersonationType();
binding.ExchangeImpersonation.ConnectingSID = new ConnectingSIDType();
binding.ExchangeImpersonation.ConnectingSID.PrimarySmtpAddress = "mailboxnamehere”;

// Call GetItemsFromInbox()
int index = 0;
bool looping = true;

while (looping)
{
    List<ItemType> items = GetItemsFromInbox(binding, index, 200, index);
    if (items == null || items.count == 0)
    {
        looping = false;
        break;
    }
    // Do your work here
}
```

Comment: Does your project reference the ews assembly?

Comment: yes. using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. This methodology only works for Exchange 2010. Since I am running Exchange 2007 I will have to figure out a completely different way to make this work.

Thank you everyone for you help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the Exchange Web Services, use the Exchange Managed API.

SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx
Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480

It's much easier to use than the WebServices.

Comment: can you elaborate on easier to use?

Comment: also that is the ews im using. isnt that the same thing?

Comment: The EWS managed API encapsulates the Exchange Web Services and provides a nice object model. It's more intuitive to use.

Answer (score 0):

[`ExchangeServiceBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.exchangeservicebinding.aspx) is contained into the `ews.dll`. According to your error, you didn't add a reference to this DLL file.

More information about [Generating Exchange Web Services Proxy Classes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2007/12/07/generating-exchange-web-services-proxy-classes.aspx):

> So now you have a code file with the autogenerated proxies. Next, you compile your code file into an assembly for use in your Exchange Web Services projects. The C# compiler is available with the Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt. Assuming that you named your code file EWS.cs, you can run the following command at the command prompt to compile your code into an assembly:

```
csc /target:library /out:EWS.dll EWS.cs
```

> Notice that EWS.dll is the name of the compiled assembly. This is how EWS.dll is created.

Comment: a search of my machine came up empty for this dll. Any idea if its in the ews package from microsoft or do i have to generate it somehow?

Comment: @toosweetnitemare Provided link to the instructions.

Comment: ty. i was just actually looking at this :) lets hope it works.

Comment: that did not work. I actually already have that webreference in my application called exchangeServiceEWS.

Comment: @toosweetnitemare Did you read the whole article? After adding the reference you need to compile the ews.dll

Comment: yes i followed the whole article. it did not fix my issue. I have now passed the code off to a coworker and hope they see something i missed. Thank you for your help VMAtm.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a WebReference to your solution to the exchange WebService.
https://exchaneServerName/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Comment: would that be a service reference or just a reference?